# How to make sure XMLHttpRequest finishes inside for loop?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've got this code that grabs the shared count number for different articles on a page.

I open an XHR for each URL and GET the graph results for it, parse the response into JSON and grab the shares. Then I run the share number through an abbreviation algorithm for more friendly numbers.

The current problem I'm having is while the for loop runs it opens all the XHRs after another, and then only proceeds to process the last one made. Somehow the other XHRs are getting abandoned.

How can I ensure that I get the results for all my requests?

```js
var counters = document.getElementsByClassName('box-counter');
for (var i = 0, n = counters.length; i < n; i++) {
  var element = counters[i],
    XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  element.innerHTML = 'unknown';
  XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200) {
      element.innerHTML = friendlyExpress(
        JSON.parse(XHR.responseText).shares
      );
    }
  }
  XHR.open(
    'GET',
    'http://graph.facebook.com/' + counters[i].parentNode.attributes['data-url'].value,
    /*async*/
    true);
  XHR.send();
}

function friendlyExpress(x, legend, power) {
  legend = 'okmgpt';
  power |= 1024;

  var powerLimit = legend.length - 1,
    powerIndex = 0;

  while (x > (power - 1) && powerIndex < powerLimit) {
    x /= power;
    powerIndex++;
  }
  return Math.round(x) + legend[powerIndex];
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section data-url="http://highline.huffingtonpost.com/articles/en/amaris-tyynismaa-runner/">
    <h3> Some Article </h3>
    <div class="box-counter"></div>
  </section>
  <section data-url="http://www.greenvilleonline.com/story/news/local/2015/05/07/stephen-colbert-funding-grant-requests-south-carolina-public-school-teachers-donorschoose-crowdfunding-site/70938100/?from=global&sessionKey=&autologin=">
    <h3> Some Article 2</h3>
    <div class="box-counter"></div>
  </section>
  <section data-url="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/05/08/us/politics/iran-bill-republicans.html">
    <h3> Some Article 3</h3>
    <div class="box-counter"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ea7qgzv8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `onreadystatechange` handler is a closure that refers to the current values of `XHR` and `element`. Since those change at each loop iteration, each handler, when it executes, refers to the latest values of `XHR` and `element`. Since the loop probably exits before the first request completes, all the handlers reference the last assigned values. To fix this, you need to capture the current values of `XHR` and `element` when declaring the handler. The easiest is with an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (you could also create a separate function to return the required function and avoid creating the closure with the wrong variables):

```
XHR.onreadystatechange = (function(elt, req) {
    return function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            elt.innerHTML = friendlyExpress(JSON.parse(req.responseText).shares);
        }
    };
}(element, XHR));
```